# DB2 column constraint for inserting values within restricted length

Tags: db2, constraints, ddl

Is there a constraint available in DB2 such that when a column is restricted to a particular length, the values are trimmed to appropriate length before insertion. For Eg. if a column has been specified to be of length 5 , inserting a value 'overflow' will get inserted as 'overf'.

Can CHECK constraint be used here? My understanding of CHECK constraint is that it will allow insertions or not allow them but it can not modify values to satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constraint isn't going to be able to do this.

A before insert trigger is normally the mechanism you'd use to modify data during an insert before it is actually placed in the table.

However, I'm reasonably sure it won't work in this case.  You'd get an SQLCODE -404 (SQLSTATE 22001) "The Sql Statement specified contains a String that is too long." thrown before the trigger gets fired.

I see two possible options
1) Create a view over the table where the column is cast to a larger size.  Then create an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view to substring the data during write.

2) Create and use a stored procedure that accepts a larger size and substrings the data then inserts it.